# Can Runnable generate an memory leak when there is Thread.sleep(long) inside?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, runnable

Can Runnable generate an memory leak when there is Thread.sleep(long) inside?

And If I will put runnable inside runnable, is there any risk?

Comment: same problem also discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914735/java-thread-sleep-leaking-threads

Comment: Short answer is yes - a thread can continue to `new` additional objects and then call `Thread.sleep()` in a loop. If you post your code the community may be able to better help.

Answer (score -1):

To directly answer to your question is NO, `Thread.sleep` alone couldn't produce any memory leaks when called within the `run()` of a runnable. A ***memory leak*** is happen when there is a object exist in heap memory which is not referenced from any running code. So `Thread.sleep` is not creating any reference-leaking objects thus non memory leak prone.

To answer your second question; is also NO. I should say that a `Runnable` generally cannot considered as a separate `Thread`, a Runnable is a simple `interface` which has a `run()` method. A `Runnable` can be submitted to a `Thread` or a `Thread Pool` though in order to execute in a separate thread. Even in that case creating and starting a `new Thread` from another `Thread` alone will not create any memory leaks.

Comment: I do not agree with this. Runnable interface is not that simple as you have presented. I saw some memory leak problems in other programs with Runnable, so it must be posible to create memory leak with basic calls from Runnable body to outside fields. Just imagine an example with asynchronous runnable and never ending while loop that is calling fields that are outside runnable with some delays by Thread.sleep(long). I do not think that garbage collector will work fine in this situation. It is important to cancel runnable if everything "special" is done.

Comment: Actually a GC should not clean up anything  in that scenario. A GC is supposed to clean up the memory which are not referenced by the running code. I think you need to read on "what is a java memory leak"[1].

For the argument ```Runnable``` is being simple or not, you could go and read the source yourself and findout.. here's the java source 

[1] https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/what-is-a-memory-leak

[2] http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Runnable.java